Issue with Audio Output on Ubuntu 22.04.4 Installed on Samsung Galaxy Book 3
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 on my Samsung Galaxy Book 3 laptop and I'm encountering some issues with the audio output. While Bluetooth and audio jack are functioning properly, I'm unable to get any output through the laptop speakers.
Upon checking the system, the output of the command lspci -nn | grep -i audio shows the following:
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)

I've tried troubleshooting this problem by exploring various solutions available online, but so far, I haven't been successful in resolving it. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has suggestions on how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance!

The first thing I always do is install the additional PulseAudio Volume Control application: sudo apt update and then sudo apt install pavucontrol and then open the app by searching for "pulseaudio volume" in your installed applications or by running the pavucontrol command. Once PulseAudio Volume Control app is open, go to the "Output Devices" tab and make sure "Show:" is set to "All Output Devices" down towards the bottom of the window. Near the top of the window, there's "Port" and a drop down menu should show the one currently selected.

Next, go to the Configuration tab and the dropdown menu for Profile should have a bunch of devices. Try selecting any one of these to see if any of them allows any additional devices available in your regular system audo settings (like the one that applies to your laptop speakers). It should be noted that sometimes devices will say "unavailable" before they are selected in the Configuration tab and that selecting them may enable one of those devices to make it available, if possible.

Just dropping you a line to say thanks for your help with the sound thing. I tried a bunch of stuff, but still no luck. Bluetooth and headphones are working fine, though!
I even gave installing Ubuntu with Windows 11 a shot, but no dice on fixing the speaker issue. Samsung support wasn't much help either, sadly.
Anyway, just wanted to give you a shoutout for trying. If you've got any other ideas, I'm all ears!
Cheers,
Carlos
